# Vue 3 - Dynamic require of "highcharts" is not supported

Tags: vue.js, highcharts, vuejs3

I am trying to include highcharts-vue like this:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'

import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'

import HighchartsVue from "highcharts-vue";


const app = createApp(App)

app.use(createPinia())
app.use(router)

app.use(HighchartsVue);

app.mount('#app')
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
 Dynamic require of "highcharts" is not supported
```

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "mwc-web",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview --port 5050"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.4",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "bootstrap-vue-3": "^0.1.9",
    "highcharts": "^10.0.0",
    "highcharts-vue": "^1.4.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "pinia": "^2.0.11",
    "vue": "^3.2.31",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^2.2.2",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^5.0.4",
    "sass": "^1.49.9",
    "sass-loader": "^12.6.0",
    "vite": "^2.8.4"
  }
}
```

vite.config.js

```js
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    exclude: ['highcharts'],
  }
})
```

babel.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
    presets: [
      '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset'
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the cause of the issue is this config:

```js
optimizeDeps: {
  exclude: ['highcharts'], // ❌ don't do this
}
```

The solution would be to remove `highcharts` from `optimizeDeps.exclude`.

Also, you don't need a Babel config when using Vite. That might be another source of the problem.

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-hightcharts-vue)

Comment: Oh cool, that seemed to work.  I was getting another error which is why I put that there, but now it's not coming up.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example of `vue3` + `highcharts-vue`: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue3-highcharts-example-k98kyz

Be sure to update to the latest versions, and to use babel or any other transpilers to work with ESM packages.

Comment: I added @vue/cli-plugin-babel but still same error.  Does the example use vite? It doesn't seem like it.

Comment: I think this is an issue when using Vite...